# Управление выключателем

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно написать: "управление выключателем" или "управление выключателя"?

Answer (score 3):

(1) Управление **выключателем** (Т.п.) - это действие.

(2) Управление **выключателя** (Р.п.) - совокупность приборов, управляющих выключателем (если выключатель имеет сложное устройство). Но обычно сложное устройство так не называют, поэтому скорее верен первый вариант.

**Из словаря**

УПРАВЛЯТЬ,  кем-чем. 3. Пользуясь какими-л. средствами, приборами и т.п., **направлять, регулировать** ход, движение, работу чего-л. Управлять **автомобилем,  штурвалом, системой пожаротушения.**

УПРАВЛЕНИЕ, 1. к Управлять . Управление **автомобилем**.  2. Административное учреждение Управление железной дороги. 3. **Совокупность приборов,** посредством которых управляют действием машины, механизма и других устройств. Рулевое **управление автомобиля**.